# Hibernate query error

Tags: java, hibernate

```
<query name="getStudyTasksByParticipantId">
            from StudyTask st 
            join (select max(lastUpdatedDate)as lastUpdatedDate, study, clinicalStudyRegistration from
                     StudyTask where clinicalStudyRegistration.participant.id in (:participantIds) 
                     group by study, clinicalStudyRegistration ) lst 
            where st.lastUpdatedDate = lst.lastUpdatedDate 
            order by st.lastUpdatedDate desc

        </query>
```

When I run this query, it gives error like `unexpected token: ( at line 3 col 30`.

What's wrong in this query

Comment: YOu don't need the brackets around participantIds, although it is odd if it causes an error. THe error it is telling you about is the one with max(. Is there a space between ) and 'as'?

Answer (score 1):

The query is not valid HQL. [The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries) says:

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where
>   clauses.

A join can only be done through an association between two entities.

Comment: A join between what and what? A subquery can only occur in the select or where clause. NOT in the from clause.